# Equalateral triangle inside circle: How long are the triangle sides?

Tags: measuring, drafting

I have a 30-inch circle (inside diameter).

If I had a equalateral triangle inside it, what would the length of the triangle sides be?

The triangle sides do not have a thickness.

Comment: I think you're lost.

Comment: It has been 45 or more years since I had do this math homework.  Unless you can show it as something to do with home DIY(homework does not count) VTC.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about geometry not DIY Home Improvement.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like homework.

Comment: @crip659 It may be a question that should be closed. But it is **not** homework. It is related to [this question about a 30" steel circle](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/279881/cut-30-circle-from-3-16-steel-plate-using-portable-bandsaw)

Comment: have voted to reopen with new information.

Comment: not home improvement .................

Comment: Tend to agree that even if specifically for home improvement purposes, home improvement is the wrong place for a basic pure-math question.

Comment: Let me introduce you to [math.se]. You'll want to check their rules, but that's a more logical place for this.

Comment: Each side of the triangle is 25.98 inches.

Answer (score 2):

[LMGTFY](https://www.merriam-webster.com/wordplay/what-does-lmgtfy-mean-let-me-google-that-for-you):

According to [this site](https://byjus.com/question-answer/if-an-equilateral-triangle-is-drawn-inside-a-circle-such-that-the-circle-is-the/) the answer is square-root of 3 x radius = ~ 26 inches.

Comment: Diameter was given, you appear to have used it as radius, rather than using half of it as radius. 25.980762113533159 - A straight line longer than the circle cannot possibly be inscribed in it.

Comment: Oops. That's what happens when I answer on my phone